# Running npm update inside dockers

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose, npm

Is there any way to run 'npm update' as a dynamic step in a docker container?
I'm guessing no, but I thought I should check if someone has a solution to this.

The reason I'd like to know is because we have a private npm package containing some common files like Mongoose models. It sometimes happens that we update this package but does not really need to redeploy any of our microservices.

So, any tips? Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you can put a cronjob in your container to check every x minutes/hours/days/ if your npm package is changed and if it is you can run npm update?

Comment: Make it part of your startup script then you can simply restart it.  Or, exec it on a running container in place with docker exec.

Comment: Cool, that'll do it, thanks!